# Java ArrayList constructor time complexity

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm doing some research into the ArrayList class as part of a school project.

In the Java API docs at Oracle's site, it mentions that all operations except a given few are "roughly linear time."

The constructors are not listed as part of the given few, but I'm having a hard time seeing how this:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
       if (initialCapacity > 0) {
           this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
       } else if (initialCapacity == 0) {
           this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
       } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                              initialCapacity);
       }
}
```

is linear time.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: That looks like constant time to me on first glance.

Comment: In addition, the constructor is called once during the lifecycle of a given `ArrayList`, so the constructor might not be considered as part of the overall running time.

Comment: Array declaration takes O(n) time. Answer is below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's linear because array declaration is O(n), as given in this question: [Java: what's the big-O time of declaring an array of size n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640850/java-whats-the-big-o-time-of-declaring-an-array-of-size-n)

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have posted, one of 3 things happen.

1. if `initialCapacity>0`, `elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];`
2. if `initialCapacity==0`, `elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;`
3. if `initialCapacity<0`, throw an exception.

All of these operations, except for number 1, take **constant time**, since no iteration over a collection is required.

Number 1 takes linear time because declaring an array of size `n` takes O(n) time. I will not re-write the entire reason, since there is a post on SO covering this somewhere. A general idea: this occurs because space has to be allocated for each of the `n` items.

I hope to have been of help. :)

Comment: I think you mean number 1

Comment: @Natecat Haha sorry :p

Comment: @Natecat's answer shows the link. But, [here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640850/java-whats-the-big-o-time-of-declaring-an-array-of-size-n) anyway.