# Hashset toList() time complexity in kotlin, is it constant or not?

Tags: time, hashset

I'd imagine it could be O(1) but can't find any info on it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the relevant implementation:

```
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.toList(): List<T> {
    if (this is Collection) {
        return when (size) {
            0 -> emptyList()
            1 -> listOf(if (this is List) get(0) else iterator().next())
            else -> this.toMutableList()
        }
    }
    return this.toMutableList().optimizeReadOnlyList()
}
```

It looks like it boils down to the usage of the `ArrayList(elements: Collection<E>)` constructor which is used in `toMutableList`. An `ArrayList` is backed by an array which results in `O(n)` time when [creating the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640850/java-whats-the-big-o-time-of-declaring-an-array-of-size-n). Please keep in mind that this eventually depends on what list implementation is used. Right now it is `ArrayList`.