# Why is time taken to access an element in a non-homogeneous list considered as constant

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is time taken to access an element in a non-homogeneous list considered as constant or How is a non-homogeneous list stored in memory in case of python?

In case of a homogeneous list, knowing the type and position, the memory location can be determined but how is it done in case of a non homogeneous list so fast as to consider it as a function of constant time?

Going through this page [Does Python use linked lists for lists? Why is inserting slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274060/does-python-use-linked-lists-for-lists-why-is-inserting-slow) I assume it stores elements in contiguous memory locations.

Comment: Each object in Python has overhead. This describes information necessary to make use of the object. The actual "data" of that doesn't need to be stored in that "header". So, a list contains just a list of references...

Comment: Python `list` is an array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: small note: Python `list`s are implemented as _dynamic_ arrays

Comment: @inspectorG4dget They are arrays in the CS sense. Random access, integer indices, contiguous indices.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: fair enough. I didn't know you meant "in the CS sense"

Answer (score 3):

Think of a list as an array of references to elements. All references have the same size; getting the reference by index is constant time, and dereferencing it is also constant time.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask what is 'dereferencing'?

Comment: @aste123: Following the reference to get to the actual object.

Answer (score 3):

A tuple is really an array of pointers to the different elements. What indexing a tuple comes down to is indexing this array of pointers (O(1)) and finding what the pointer we grab points to (O(1)).

You can see this for yourself in [`tupleobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/35da5d848ffd/Objects/tupleobject.c) and [`tupleobject.h`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/35da5d848ffd/Include/tupleobject.h). The code for indexing a tuple is:

```c
PyObject *
PyTuple_GetItem(PyObject *op, Py_ssize_t i)
{
    if (!PyTuple_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    if (i < 0 || i >= Py_SIZE(op)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_IndexError, "tuple index out of range");
        return NULL;
    }
    return ((PyTupleObject *)op) -> ob_item[i];
}
```

You can see that the last line indexes the underlying C array: `ob_item[i]` (after some preliminary checks). `ob_item` is really an array of `PyObject` pointers:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    PyObject *ob_item[1];

    /* ob_item contains space for 'ob_size' elements.
     * Items must normally not be NULL, except during construction when
     * the tuple is not yet visible outside the function that builds it.
     */
} PyTupleObject;
```