# Optimal vector data structure?

Tags: data-structures, vector, language-agnostic, dynamic-arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A data structure supporting O(1) random access and worst-case O(1) append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834490/a-data-structure-supporting-o1-random-access-and-worst-case-o1-append)

I saw an answer a while ago on StackOverflow regarding a provably *optimal* `vector` ("array list") data structure, which, if I remember correctly, *lazily* copied elements onto a larger vector so that it wouldn't cause a huge pause every time the vector reallocated.

I remember it needed O(sqrt(n)) extra space for bookkeeping, and that the answer linked to a published paper, but that's about it... I'm having a really hard time searching for it (you can imagine that searches like *optimal vector* are getting me nowhere).

Where can I find the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the paper you are referring to is ["Resizable Arrays in Optimal Time and Space"](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1999/09/CS-99-09.pdf) by Brodnik et al.  Their data structure uses the lazy copying dynamic array you mentioned in your question as a building block to assemble this structure.  There is [this older question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834490/a-data-structure-supporting-o1-random-access-and-worst-case-o1-append) describing the lazy-copying data structure, which might be useful to get a better feel for how it works.

Hope this helps!