# O(1) append and O(1) random access data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

I was wondering if there was any **append-only** data structure that supports **worst-case** O(1) appending, and random access.

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4834508/15510261), but the problem in my eyes is that whenever you fill up the array, you have to allocate a new array that's twice the size, so that would be O(n) worst case for appending.

However, I saw one of the answers in that question was to use `std::deque`. It also said that `std::deque` supports O(1) random access & insertion. Is that true?

I'm using C++.

Comment: How is your question different from the question you've linked to?

Comment: Perhaps [`std::colony`](http://wg21.link/p0447)?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's not different, but the answer for that question doesn't really answer my question because it has to reallocate another array twice the size

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [A data structure supporting O(1) random access and worst-case O(1) append?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834490/a-data-structure-supporting-o1-random-access-and-worst-case-o1-append) Any new answers should go to that question.

Comment: I think the question should probably be worded differently. Maybe something like, "Why is the answer given there O(1) and not O(n)?"

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot - nice! But: `an O(1) time complexity [ ] operator is not possible and the container is bidirectional, but not random-access.`

Comment: The cost of allocation is not (usually) proportional to the size.

Comment: It's going to be worth looking into amortized cost.

Comment: *Is that true?*  No, it's O(1)(amortized), so the worst case is O(n).

Comment: I have set the question as duplicate, but I highly support writing new answers in that question so OP has something that suit its needs. If there are compelling reasons to remove the duplicate, please ping me.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I think I was wrong, allocations might actually be O(1)

Comment: @WowThere yes. I would expect it to be constant time, but less predictable. Any allocation can be from almost instantly to taking a considerable amount of time.

Comment: Another trick would be to have a maximum size a preallocate everything beforehand. That will cost a lot of memory, but will be faster. I also suggest looking at [`pinned_vector`](https://github.com/mknejp/vmcontainer), which is a vector that does resize its buffer in place using virtual memory. I haven't found the implementation, try asking the author.